# Object Composition C++: no matching function for call

Tags: c++, class, composition

I am trying to create an object named **luminary**. This object is composed of **thermometer** object, **memory** object, **Led** Object. The last three classes are working perfectly separated. But when I try to glue everything together in the luminary class I got these message:

luminary.cpp:11:112: error: no matching function for call to ‘Thermometer::Thermometer()’
luminary.cpp:11:112: error: no matching function for call to ‘Memory::Memory()’
luminary.cpp:11:112: error: no matching function for call to ‘Led::Led()’

Code for header file of luminary class:

```
class Luminary{

public:
    //Constructor
    Luminary(Led led,Thermometer thermometer,Memory memory);

    //Atributes
    Led _led;
    Thermometer _thermometer;
    Memory _memory;
}
```

Code for cpp file:

```
#include "luminary.h"
#include "Led.h"
#include "Thermometer.h"
#include "Memory.h"


//Constructor
Luminary::Luminary(Led led,Thermometer thermometer,Memory memory){

    _memory = memory;
    _thermometer = thermometer;
    _led = led;

}
```

Why do I get these messages?

Comment: You need to define default constructors for `Led`, `Thermometer`, and `Memory`

Comment: @ForhadAhmed: Unlikely. This is a basic "assigning rather than initialising" mistake, and hacking around that by giving classes default constructors that make zero sense is not the proper solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to your source, `Led`, `Thermometer`, `Memory` have to be default constructible, means they should have a default constructor, but they haven't.

You could use [member initializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) here:

```
Luminary::Luminary(Led led,Thermometer thermometer,Memory memory) 
    : _led(led), _thermometer(thermometer), _memory(memory) {}
```

[Here](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#init-lists) is a discussion about why in moust cases, you should use initialization lists rather than assignment.

Comment: @GabrielVilella I've added a reference for further information, hope it could help you more.